# Ways to open a folder/explorer client side from a web page.... Java applet?

Tags: java, directory

I have a need to "pop up" operating system folders from my web app, mostly to locate files in them.  My users don’t want to use a conventional web upload/download paradigm.  I have 7 or 8 static folders that need to be opened in explorer on a PC or in Finder on a mac.  These folders are all network available, but are buried, and for convenience need to be shown on a web page.

There are IE tricks to do this, and I've written a sample flash app that only allows the browser to open, but I know most browsers sandbox this, and keep me from calling these folders.  I am aware that some Java libraries deal with the opening of folders, does anyone have any thoughts or samples for this?

Comment: Could you clarify your question some more?

Comment: Hmm... not really ;)  It's a pretty simple need.  From a web page, need to fire an applet that will open the client side pointer to the folder - not the browser showing the folder contents.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can imagine is to create a Signed Java Applet.

Applets cannot access the filesystem (and a lot of other ressources) if they are not valid signed. Maybe you can also grant the permission by a policyfile.

There ist a tutorial [at JavaRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/HowCanAnAppletReadFilesOnTheLocalFileSystem).

But I am not sure, if this solution will be very helpful, because the JavaPlugin will be removed from a lott of browsers in near future. (I think FireFox already removed it).

I think there is actually **NO** solution to this problem.

There may be some workarrounds:

1. Put a Batch-File onto the server, which opens the folder, if executed
2. Can you create a local  service, which handles requests from you webpage and opens the folder.
3. Create a webapplication, which opens the folder at serverside, and create a webpage, which displays the content in you website.